# Reading selected Items from QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

How can read selected items from QTableWidget?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`int QTableWidget::currentRow() const`
Returns the row of the current item.

`int QTableWidget::currentColumn() const`
Returns the column of the current item.

Answer (score 3):

Some options (there are also others out there too):

```
# selectedRanges(), would give you the second cell from each selected row, for example:
indexes = []
for selectionRange in myTable.selectedRanges():
    indexes.extend(range(selectionRange.topRow(), selectionRange.bottomRow()+1))
    print "indexes", indexes      # indexes is a list like [0, 2] of selected rows

for i in indexes:
    print "specific item", myTable.item(i, 1).text()
    results.append( str(myTable.item(i, 1).text()) )

# selectedItems()
for item in myTable.selectedItems():
    print "selectedItems", item.text()

# selectedIndexes()
for item in myTable.selectedIndexes():
    print "selectedIndexes", item.row(), item.column()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`selectedItems`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems) function to retrieve the selected items or the [`selectedIndexes`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#selectedIndexes) to get all selected cells including empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to access the items in a qtablewidget is using the function

QList QTableWidget::selectedRanges () const